# Max number of file extensions that matter in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a max number of file extensions that matter in Rails?

For example, I've seen two chained file extensions such as `index.html.erb`.

I think I've even seen one more level of file extensions as with `example.js.coffee.erb`.

I'm asking because with JavaScript files it's customary to have many dots in a file name like `jquery-ui.custom.calendar.min.js` but I'm wondering if this interferes with Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Rails doesn't see .custom.calendar as real extensions so it ignores them. I use jQuery files with multiple dots a lot and it never threw out an error.

Comment: It would be great to see this in the docs, but I couldn't find it.  I'll accept this answer if there are no others.

Comment: Yeah you are right there isn't many information available about it but you can check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/asset_pipeline.html and at chapter 2.4 it explains what the multiple extensions on a rails file do.

Comment: Thanks for the link!